# Bootstrap collapse is hiding all links in a large viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the collapse function in Bootstrap after watching some tutorials I tried it out myself and I am left with no links showing on a large viewport.

Here is my code does anbody notice anything that might be wrong with it?

The HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default affix-top nav-links" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"> 
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="media/img/nav-logo.png" alt="Driven Car Sales Logo" class="img-rounded logo-nav navbar-brand"></a>
    </div>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Used Cars</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Get Finance</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Driven<strong class="caret"></strong></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
               <a href"#">The Team</a>
              </li>
              <li>
               <a href"#">Our Partners</a>
              </li>
             </ul> <!--Drop Down End-->
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">How To Find Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>    
    </div>
</nav>
```

The custom CSS:

```
.logo-nav {
height: 2.3em;
width: auto;
}
.brand {
font-size: 2em;
margin: 20px 0 25px;
}
.navbar-brand {
opacity: 0;
color: #ff0066;
-webkit-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in;
-moz-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in;
-o-transition:opacity 0.3s ease-in;
transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;

margin-left: 0px;
}
.navbar {
border-radius: 0px;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-    default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
color: #fff;
background-color: #DD3B4D;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-menu {
color: #fff;
background-color: #DD3B4D;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
color: #fff;
}

nav.affix {
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
}
nav.affix .navbar-brand {
opacity: 1;
height: 2.3em;
width: auto;
}

.navbar-header {
width: 0px;
-webkit-transition:width .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:width .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:width .4s ease-in-out;
transition:width .4s ease-in-out;
margin: 0 1em 0 1em
}

nav.affix .navbar-header {
width: 8em;
-webkit-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}

.nav-links {
font: 600 15px/1.5 'Arimo';
}

.navbar-nav > li:last-child{
border-right: 1px solid #475d88;
}

ul.nav a:hover { 
color: #fff !important;
background-color: #DD3B4D !important;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
-o-transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

nav.affix .navbar-brand { 
display: inline-block; 
}
```

Sorry for the amount of CSS I didn't realise how much there was ha.

I have had a good play about and can't seem to stop this from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `collapse` class

Link http://jsfiddle.net/LvhCh/1/

`<div class="nav-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-nav">`

Comment: Thanks that worked! I am trying to toggle that menu so there is a button that will open and close that menu however I just can't get a button to display in the right of that nav bar :( I hate to go a little off topic but I have tried and it just doesn't appear I don't suppose you could show me an example could you?

Comment: Where is the button...I mean which element ? I might be able to.

Comment: I managed to get it appear using:

    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>

However it doesn't open and collapse. It's just below the div container element.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/LvhCh/2/ Add this: `.navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}`

Comment: Before I post again how do I make it display only on smaller devices? I mean I could just add some media queries but there must be a better way. I've been searching for the past 2 hours haha

Comment: By default, it's only present for mobile, if you want for desktop view add the css `.navbar-toggle {   display: block; }`

Comment: How strange mine appears even on large devices. I have it on a live site and on JSfiddle the button doesn't dissolve when the view-port is widened:

http://jsfiddle.net/nickmadd/LvhCh/4/

Comment: You can add media query and do `display: none;` for smaller devices

Comment: Sorry for the confusing if you look here:
http://www.dealerbyte.co.uk/

You will notice that it has the button on the large viewport?